# Writing Chess Game, Trouble Getting One Square Object From Another

Tags: java

I'm writing a chess game.  My basic design is to have a 2d array (8 x 8) consisting of square objects.  Squares have a number of fields, including file (a char) and rank (an int).

My getNewSquare method takes a starting square and returns the square [vertical] squares above it and [horizontal] squares to the right of it.  Negative parameters just go the opposite direction.  If the parameters take us off the board, the method should return null.

```
public static Square getNewSquare (Square start, int vertical, int horizontal) {
    int squareNumber = start.getNumberFromSquare();
    //see if too far right or left
    if ((int) (start.file - 'a') + horizontal >= 8 || (int) (start.file - 'a') + horizontal < 0) {
        return null;
    //see if too far up or down
    } else if ( start.rank + vertical >= 8 || start.rank + vertical < 0) {
        return null;
    //otherwise         
    } else {
        squareNumber += (8 * vertical + horizontal);
        return getSquareFromNumber(squareNumber);
    }   
}
```

I have two helper functions, getNumberFromSquare and getSquareFromNumber.  Basically each square object has a number.  Top left is 0, bottom right is 63.  You increment from left to right, top to bottom.

```
public int getNumberFromSquare() {
    return (int) (this.file - 'a') + (8 - this.rank) * 8;
}

public static Square getSquareFromNumber(int candidate) {
    char myFile = (char) (candidate % 8 + 'a');
    int myRank = 8 - (candidate / 8);
    return new Square(myFile, myRank);
}
```

When I run this code:

```
Square south = Square.getNewSquare(start, -1, 0);
System.out.println("starting south square is " + south.getFile() + south.getRank());
```

I get "starting south square is a9", which shouldn't be possible as ranks > 8 aren't allowed.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: What is the value of `start`?  It affects how `getNewSquare` is doing its operation (I suspect that `start.rank` is either 7 or 8).

Comment: value of start is the top left square

Comment: I realise this doesn't answer your question, but from a design perspective, I would recommend creating a Board class whose responsibility is to manage the Square objects. I would also make each Square object aware of it's location on the board in terms of row and column (as integers). Then you ask the Board object for a Square either at a specific coordinate, or relative to another Square.

Comment: I'm talking about actual numerical values.  The way that I see this breaking is if `(candidate / 8) == -1`.

Comment: Off the top of my head, it appears that every time you call `getSquareFromNumber` you create a new `Square` object.  So if you have a square at (2,3) and go one square east, you create a new `Square` at (3,3); if you take your new square and go one square west, you create a new `Square` for (2,3), which will be a separate object from the `Square` you started with.  I foresee problems with this.  If you have multiple `Square`'s with the same coordinates, which one do you put a piece on?  I think Jason is on the right track.

Comment: @Jason I'd still like to be able to have some way of referencing a square as "a4" or "b7", but I'm a bit unsure how to make use of my 2d array of integers (which is what I have as a field of my Board class).

Comment: @Mariogs The thing is that "a4" or "b7" are really only for the presentation layer. Internally, it is easier to refer to squares by two dimensional index. But nevertheless, you should be able to write a simple function that converts "a4" into 1,4 and "b7" into 2,7 (or 0,3 and 1,6 if you are using 0-based indexing).

Comment: You may want to consider not returning null at all - this mean you will have to check the value returned every time before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Your tests seem to run things between 0 and 8 inclusive; surely they should be 0 to 7.  But you should put this in a debugger with some test calls and debug it, there's little point in trying to figure out what's wrong without doing that.

Comment: Chess isn't zero-based.

Comment: Agree, but my underlying 2d array representing the board is

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but advice on improving your program.  I've written a complete chess engine + ai + gui available on github ([BlackWidow](https://github.com/amir650/BlackWidow-Chess)) that you can reference.

Instead of having a 2d array (8x8), why not have a simpler, 1-d array of `Square`'s that are simply numbered `0->63`.  If you ever want to resolve the rank or file of a square, just have a utility class that has global static boolean arrays

```
boolean [] FIRST_ROW = new boolean[64];
FIRST_ROW[0] = true;
FIRST_ROW[1] = true;
....
```

Then you can simply say: `FIRST_ROW[Square.getCoordinate()]` to answer whether or not a given `Square` is on a particular rank or file.  This approach is simpler and more readable in the long run.  Adding and subtracting characters and ints just seems unnecessary here.

One dimensional arrays will also perform better, but thats irrelavent at this point in your project.